# Installing Python modules without command prompt.

Tags: python, installation, pip

I have Python on my school computer, but I would like to install a few modules. How could I get passed this problem.

Comment: Passed **what** problem???

Comment: You can ask the SysAdmin to install it for you since you don't have access to the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('pip install X --target=d:\some\folder\with\write\permission', shell=True)
```

Is a python script that will try to install the package X in some folder that you want. Maybe this way you can do it.

Comment: Come to that, `subprocess.call('bash')` or `subprocess.call('cmd.exe')`

Comment: Who ever locked up the computers were not consistent. Any processes that uses CMD fails, but using PowerShell I created an administrator account and upgraded my standard account admin privileges

Answer (score 1):

I installed python packages in school with this.

open a python shell and write the following:

```
import pip
pip._internal.main(["install", "--user", <PACKAGE>])
```

Comment: If the pip version is lower than 10 you can try instead of pip._internal.main(["install", "--user", <PACKAGE>]) with pip.main(["install", "--user", <PACKAGE>])

Answer (score 1):

For school computers that don't allow you install libraries via cmd here's a way around it!

```
import pip
```

press enter

```
pip.main(["install", "--user", "Libraryname"])
```

"user" may not be important so only use it if it doesn't work the first time running it

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by running the following:

```
import os
os.system('pip install --user X')
```

which did not require admin privileges.
You may then need to add the packages directory to the path

Answer (score 0):

You can also install libraries from powershell if using a windows computer.
First open up IDLE

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('powershell.exe')
```

After powershell opens it automatically opens to the python directory. You want to go back to `C:` with `cd..`. From there use cd users and cd yourusername. It should look like.

```
PS C:/users/your username>
```

Set environment with

```
$env:path="$env:Path;c:/path/to/python/folder"
```

After this you can do a standard pip install.

```
python -m pip install <pythonlibrary>
```